Back ticks - subqueries - BigQuery SQL
I'm wondering why only sometimes BigQuery SQL requires me to use back ticks around my project name.
For example:
FROM bigquery-public-data.fda_food.food_events      

vs
FROM `bigquery-public-data.fda_food.food_events`

I guess the only difference is in one query I used a subquery and the other I did not. Could this be why?

So are you saying you needed backticks in one query but not the other for the exact same project/database/table? Or maybe the one which needs the backticks have a reserved keyword in the project/database/table name?

Far as I know, you would only need to use backticks if your object name is a reserved word (bad practice), or has spaces in it (also a bad practice)

Click on 'edited' under your post to see how it has been edited. Backquote is a SE markdown editor meta character. Read the edit '?' help & advanced help re formats for code (etc).

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
